# Gravity Forms Dynamically Populate Post/Page Category

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I would like to be able to use the same form on several pages, and know which page a submitted form came from. For a long list of reasons, I need to do that based on category.

I found code to add categories to pages, works great.

But I can't figure out how to get Gravity Forms to dynamically populate a field with the category.

I've selected "Allow field to be populated dynamically" on the form, I've set the parameter name to "pagecategory"

Here's what I've got - it does nothing:

```
//Get Page Category - For Demo Form
add_filter("gform_field_value_pagecategory", "populate_pagecategory");

function populate_pagecategory($value){
    global $post; 
    $value = get_the_category( $post->ID,'metakeyname',true);
   return $value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

get_the_category() actually returns an array of all category that is assigned to that post. The code below works for me to fetch the name of first category only.

```
//Get Page Category - For Demo Form
add_filter("gform_field_value_pagecategory", "populate_pagecategory");

function populate_pagecategory($value){
    global $post; 
    $categories = get_the_category( $post->ID,'metakeyname',true);
    $value = $categories[0]->cat_name;
    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit surprised this type of need/question isn't more prevalent. I had to do this same thing, but for a custom taxonomy. In case anyone lands here in need of how to do Mash's answer, but with a custom taxonomy, the following is working for me. My custom taxonomy is "services," which you can see replaces 'metakeyname' in Mash's answer.

```
  //Get Page Custom Taxonomy - For Gravity Forms
add_filter("gform_field_value_pagecategory", "populate_pagecategory");

function populate_pagecategory($value){
    global $post; 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID,'services',true);
    $value = $terms[0]->name;
    return $value;
}
```